# Access IBM DVM(Data Virtualization Manager) from linux Unbuntu vm using Python

Tags: ubuntu, jdbc, jaydebeapi, data-virtualization, dvm

I am trying to access IBM DVM(Data Virtualization Manager) from linux Unbuntu vm using Python.

**I have installed JAVA on the unbuntu machine:**
java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b08, mixed mode)

**I have also installed JayDeBeAPI:**
pip install JayDeBeApi

Installing collected packages: packaging, JPype1, JayDeBeApi
Successfully installed JPype1-1.4.1 JayDeBeApi-1.2.3 packaging-23.0

**From IBM website i have download the DVM-JDBC3.1 driver**

https://ak-delivery04-mul.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/IMA/0bb4c/0/dvm-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.zip
Unzipped to /opt/dvm-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.

**I have also set the class path:**
echo $CLASSPATH

/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554:/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar:

**Now I am trying to Run the following python code to connect to DVM**

import jpype

import jaydebeapi

dvm_driver_path = "/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar"

jpype.addClassPath('/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar')
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % ('/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar'))

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver.class',
'jdbc:dv://###:##/###',
{'user': '#####', 'password': '####'},
'/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar')

if (conn):
print('Connected')
else:
print('Failed to connect')

but i am getting the following error:
python3 dvm-jdbc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dvm-jdbc.py", line 26, in 
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver.class',
File "/home/sanika/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py", line 412, in connect
jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
File "/home/sanika/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py", line 221, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
jpype.JClass(jclassname)
File "/home/sanika/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 99, in **new**
return _jpype._getClass(jc)
TypeError: Class com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver.class is not found

**Is my driver class wrong?
If so what is the correct one?**

Answer (score 0):

The correct class name should be 'com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver' , so your connection line should be

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver', 'jdbc:dv://###:##/###', {'user': '#####', 'password': '####'}, '/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554.jar')
```

also make sure the path to the JDBC driver is correct, because you are mentioning `/opt/dvm-jdbc-3.1.202303130554` and `/opt/dv-jdbc-3.1.202303130554` in your code.

Comment: Hi @Saxtheowl
i tried using "com.rs.jdbc.dv.DvDriver' but now i am getting "java.sql.java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:dv:"

Comment: Make sure the path to the JDBC driver is correct